# Biostrings: Using subseq on a XStringSet-class object with vmatchPattern results

Tags: r, bioinformatics

Hello I'm very new to the usage of BioStrings, but I can see glimpses of its power. I hope somebody could help me get started:

I load a fastafile into a XStringSet-class object

```
genes <- readDNAStringSet(File = "filename", format = "fasta", use.names = T)
```

I search a specific string:

```
view <- vmatchPatter(pattern = "CCGGA", genes)
matches <- unlist(view, recursive = T, use.names = T)
m <- as.matrix(matches)
```

I know have a neat matrix containing all the locations of a match. It is relatively easy to obtain the context of a match in a specific gene using the following code:

```
subseq(genes["genename",], start = m["genename",1], width = 20)
```

However, I'm sure there is a very fast way to get all the context of all the genes in a quick way. Also taking in regard the possible multiple matches in a certain DNA sequence

Can somebody please kickstart me?

Comment: You'll get definitive answers about Bioconductor packages on the Bioconductor [mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/mailform/)

Comment: thanks for the tip, I've forwarded my question there. Probably this platform is too broad for such a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution which is half working since it disregards the multiple hits. I'm sure there is a more symantic solution that is integral to Biostrings but this it works for me so far:

`subseq(genes[rownames(m),], start = m[rownames(m),1], width = 20) ### for multiple genes`